# Analog vs digital wireless newbie questions

Tags: digital-logic, wireless, analog

As i try to understand the real difference between analog wireless and Digital wireless i'm asking some questions :
As far as i know digital means more accuracy of data, but require larger bandwith to reproduce same as analog
thats why continuous stream as audio or video are hard to send digitally, but easier with a powerful and calibrated analog rf transmitter.

But for small analog stuff, let say i just need to send an analog "tilt" or simple analog accelerometer ( just motion activated ) wirelessly to engage a led to the receiver side, do i really need to consider it digitally ? Can i make an analog a link tilt sensor/tx to rx/led without mcu in the way?

I'm trying to do a very tiny project where form factor is key, and where data doesn't have to be that accurate, is it possible doing it analog all the way?

Second question:

To the other extreme, what is the best solution to send continuous or large digital data wirelessly ? (lets says 24bits/48khz audio ?)

Third and final question:

How can i calculate easily my needs in terms of kbps if I go digital, or bandwidth/power when doing analog.

Comment: "Digital" does not necessarily imply a MCU...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your accelerometer outputs an analog voltage, the signal coming out of the accel. would be DC.  You *could* potentially create a circuit where the accel. signal could affect the modulation index for AM transmission therefore indirectly transmitting the "accel. data."

But I wouldn't go there.

It's a lot easier to just hook up the accel. to a microcontroller and use something like an XBee to transmit data wirelessly to your LED.  You don't even need a big fancy microcontroller to do the job.  Something like the ATTiny 84 can do the job.

Comment: Digital signal is more resistant to noise. Since you know what to expect you can remove the noise and recover the digital signal. In analog it is very difficult/impossible to remove noise if it falls within the signal bandwidth. If noise is not a problem then you can go with analog signal too.